# Cannot read property of 'watchlist' undefined

Tags: javascript, authentication

```
 authenticate(request, response) {
    const user = userstore.getUserByEmail(request.body.email);
    if (user) {
      response.cookie('watchlist', user.email);
      logger.info('logging in' + user.email);
      response.redirect('/start');
    } else {
      response.redirect('/login');
    }
  },

 getCurrentUser (request) {
  const userEmail = request.cookies.watchlist;
  return userstore.getUserByEmail(userEmail);
  }
}
```

Here the code authenticates a user and up above it defines 'watchlist' as a cookie, however it keeps telling me it is undefined. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please share more details for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getUserByEmail` is probably an async function. Be sure use `await` to make sure that we wait for the promise to resolve and return a value before moving to the next line. In your case it will look like this:

```
 async authenticate(request, response) {
    const user = await userstore.getUserByEmail(request.body.email);
    if (user) {
      response.cookie('watchlist', user.email);
      logger.info('logging in' + user.email);
      response.redirect('/start');
    } else {
      response.redirect('/login');
    }
  },

 async getCurrentUser (request) {
  const userEmail = request.cookies.watchlist;
  return await userstore.getUserByEmail(userEmail);
  }
}
```

Further reading: [JavaScript Async Await](https://javascript.info/async-await)